# How to disable whatsapp backing up images

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

My whatsapp backups are getting huge, and Yes I checked that the "Back up videos" option is unchecked.
One single backup is about **312 MB** plus the fact that whastapp keeps 7 backups
That totals to **2.1GB** of used up space.

I personally don't mind having backups of actual "text messages" but I don't want image backups, since most of my images are just memes,reposts, nothing important.

Things I have tried, 
I deleted all my whatsapp images and runned a backup after, the backup was still the same size.

So is there a way to:

1. Make the backups **smaller** by preventing image backups.
2. Delete the images in the Whatsapp threads without clearing all chat.
3. Reduce **7 day backups** to maybe **2 day backups** without deleting manually everyday.

Any solution that addresses one of the above will be appreciated.
I am also open to solutions that involve mods, root-only, xposed-framework, etc

Comment: [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.mark.timelycleaner) claims scheduled cleaning. Not tried by me

Comment: just tested and works for solving problem 2, hopefully there is a way to solve for 1 and 3

Comment: Whatsapp uses proprietary APIs and is difficult for developers to crack. Even with Xposed modules, you see them failing with subsequent editions. IMO, very unlikely that they will be solved but if 2 is solved and applied daily, then won't the backups be reduced in size? To that extent the solution may work